# Is it possible to do a request via the SettingsAPI without asking for Google's location service?

Tags: android, geolocation

The [settingsAPI](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) is a useful API to ask a user for changing his device settings. When using this API and testing my app, it always seems to ask for this option:

> Use Google's location service, sending anonymous location to google
>   even when no apps are running.

Is it possible to do exactly this request without this specific option? Other options (like if you need GPS data) can be influenced by changing the priority.

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.

SettingsApi doesn't allow you to specify location providers directly (GPS location, network location provider, etc). Instead, you can only ask for  [location priorities](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int)), and SettingsApi chooses location providers for you.

Unfortunately there's no GPS-only location priority. So any location priority you asked for implies that network location provider is needed. If the user hasn't "permanently agreed" to use Google's location service before, the consent text will be shown in location settings dialog.

So, if you don't want to see the consent text, just "permanently agree" to it before you launch location settings dialog. To do that, go to system "Settings" => "Location", toggle the location switch off and on. You'll see a dialog like this:

[image: Google Location Service Dialog]

Check "Don't show again", then "Agree". Next time when location settings dialog is shown, the consent text will not be there.